# Does video tag (HTML 5) injection via JavaScript work in any browsers?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html, html5-video, code-injection

I'm trying to dynamically spawn a video element on a page using JavaScript.

**JavaScript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var video = $(document.createElement('video'))
    .attr('id', 'VideoElement')
    .attr('controls', 'controls')
    .attr('src', 'videopath.mp4') // Changed 'href' attribute to 'src'
    .css({
      width: 640,
      height: 360
    });
  $('#VideoContainer').append(video);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body>  
  <div id="VideoContainer"></div>
</body>
```

In Firefox I get the video harness, but the actual video doesn't load.
In IE8 the video harness doesn't even appear.

Is HTML 5 just not supported enough to accomplish this yet?

**Edit**:
Got this to work with Artiom's fix.
Looks like this works fine with Chrome and Safari. I'm using a codec Firefox doesn't support, so it doesn't work there; although I suspect it will work with a supported codec. IE8 sure enough doesn't work (*high five IE*).

Comment: You can combine that `attr` call into a single call passing an object like you're doing with `css`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think you're using the wrong attribute there :)

Replace the `href` attribute with the `src` attribute in your video tag, and I'm pretty sure it should work :P

Answer (score 0):

ie8 doesn't support it for sure.

Have you checked out the various jQuery-based media players? You can find ones that use html5 by default and fall back to flash in browsers that don't support it.